# Make reference to a bibliography subsection generated by biblatex

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I am using biblatex in my document. I have divided the bibligraphy in 2 subsections, one for scientific articles and the other for codes and regulations. For that I used keywords, as suggested in the biblatex manual.

```
\printbibheading[heading=bibnumbered]
\printbibliography[keyword=article,heading=subbibnumbered,title={Scientific articles}]
\printbibliography[keyword=regulation,heading=subbibnumbered,title={Codes and regulations}]
```

I am using `heading = subbibnumbered` because I want this bibliography subsections to be considered like `subsection`, numbered and included in the table of contents.

This works fine. Now I want to make a reference to this subsections, but I don't know how to make it. Does biblatex use a `\label` when making this subsections? Is it possible to define one?

I have tried to include a label after the call to `\printbibliography`. The link points to the correct position but the number of the section refered is the previous to the bibliography ones.

I have searched in the biblatex manual and in Stack Exchange, but I haven't find this question answered, sorry if it already is.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome, have you tried putting a label within the title? `title={Scientific articles\label{sciArticles}}` Haven't tested it, but i think this could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the label within the title.

[image: juanBiblatexRef]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
Interested in articles? See \autoref{bib:article}\par
Interested in books? See \autoref{bib:book}\par
\printbibliography[type=article,title={The articles\label{bib:article}},heading=bibnumbered]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={The books\label{bib:book}},heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty clever. I used to use `\AtBeginBibliography{\label{bibliography}}`, but, of course, that works only if you have only one bibliography. If you want to keep the same name, use `title={\bibname\label{bib:book}}` for instance.